# Is there a way to integrate facebook onto an app and share images?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am familair with integrating Facebook,and using it for user login and updating statuses .

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to  share images as well rather that simple text .
I have check the internet for sometime for its tutorial but I did not find any .
My final objective is to integrate twitter and instagram as well , so that when i click a button  an image will be shared on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Simple Facebook https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook which provide a way to publish photo on Facebook : https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook/wiki/Publish-photo

If you look at the source code of the lib you will find how to implement it without using this library